# Best position for contour placement

Tags: algorithm, contour

I have a graph where the nodes represent cities (City object has population and coordinates as fields) and the edges represent the distance between them. How to calculate the center of a circular contour, so that it covers the most population (not node count!)? 
1)The graph is used to represent infrastructural state, which is irrelevant for the question at hand.
2)The circle itself is constrained by size (radius). Basically, I'm trying to simulate a nuclear hit.

Is there an out of the box algorithm  for this?

Comment: Two questions : 1) How is the graph relevant ? Is it not only about covering cities, and therefore only the population and coordinates are useful ? 2) What constraints do you impose on your contour ? Without constraints, you could just take a circle around all cities, thus maximizing the population count (and there is an algorithm to find a circle that, in addition, is tight)

Comment: 1)The graph is used to represent infrastructural state, which is irrelevant for the question at hand. 2)The circle itself is constrained by size (radius).
Basically, I'm trying to simulate a nuclear hit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you should update your question with the precisions you gave me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `R` the radius of the circle that you want to place, `N` the number of cities, `Pi` the population of the ith city, we use this one key observation :

> An optimal circle can always be moved slightly so that it still covers the same cities but now touches two cities.

The following picture illustrates this : the dash-lined circle is optimal, and can be moved slightly to an also optimal circle that goes through exactly 2 points

```html
<head>
<title>Untitled Diagram</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#ffffff;">
<div class="mxgraph" style="position:relative;overflow:auto;width:100%;">
<div style="width:1px;height:1px;overflow:hidden;">1ZfNjtowEMefhjuJw9expdv2UqkSh7ZHb2ISa50YOWaBffod45kEhyDtIaQLSCj+2x6PfzNjnAlbl8cfhu+KXzoTahJPs+OEfZvE8WKVwK8TTl6YL6ZeyI3MvBS1wka+CRRp2F5mog4GWq2VlbtQTHVVidQGGjdGH8JhW63CVXc8pxVbYZNyda3+kZktvLqM563+U8i8oJWj+cr3PPP0JTd6X+F6k5htzx/fXXKyhRutC57pQyAdp2iUoc0TCQkKO14Fbr5pXQaCEXWDFK1uJfqK7WdtMmG8RJqS1cslOPYEITZaw0z3VB7XQrkwUwj9tO83ehuGRlTB2rcmQJeb8MrVHn1HRvZEcYEJkALQ+HoopBWbHU9dzwGSELTClgpaETyiKWGswJzscafdJOSx0KWw5uQCgO5QMmIOR5TDhzYjohlqxWU2kMgRZt7YbncPDwigHwYbEMZWKrXWSrtwV7pyMzJeF8ItNRQs1oFFDEaBNfsArCr74g4GaKWK17VMQ0awT3P6Cw0oNt/4Rz1HaZsOeCa9B6HIro6VDkDwSe/NOU5tkC03ucBRZ8+vMV9g7KNImhGKW/kaOtFHFlf4rSW410SRdVI+oaiSCe88zros5Y6hxiE0FC87hvyWrwydA91s+0OxxyN58EKBk3t6/g5UIHR6UIGsegqkrz4GKI/FYyBiM6xjShqG7REQLR8ki6iOKIvm4yHCy8ejIYrn4xUa2fj0lUY3vv/BCL399HmUdBgl45VaNORV+I6Mklt/82MwutcNeWBG0VUe3Y0RNNu3NX+Vat/O2dM7</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.draw.io/js/embed-static.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

So the algorithm is as follows :

> Iterate over all pairs of points at distance less than R.
>
> > For each pair, compute the two circles of radius R that go through them.
> >
> > > For each circle, compute the total population within by computing how many cities are contained inside.

Here are the circles I mean by `the two circles of radius R that go through them` :

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Diagram</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#ffffff;">
<div class="mxgraph" style="position:relative;overflow:auto;width:100%;">
<div style="width:1px;height:1px;overflow:hidden;">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</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.draw.io/js/embed-static.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

A trivial implementation of this yields an `O(n^3)` algorithm (there are `O(n^2)` pairs of points, and computing the total population within a circle takes time `O(n)` when it is done by checking for every city whether it is inside or not).

If that complexity is not good enough, you will need to try more complex things. Some stuffs that comes to mind to improve the previous solution are : sorting the cities according to x, y, an arbitrary direction and/or a combinations of them (you can test much less pairs of points using this, also quickly restrict what cities might be contained in your circle), and storing the cities in a quadtree. Constructing a combinatorial map corresponding to drawing circles around each city could also work (not sure about the complexity of this, and it is quite complex ...) .